# Comparing contents in two csv file line by line using python

Tags: python

Hi I need to do following steps while comparing two csv files using python:

0) open file 1 and file 2

1) read one line from file 1

2) read one line from file 2

3) compare contents in each of line and count number of same and different

4) if contents are different, write contents in file 1 and file 2 in an output file

5) go back to step 1) before reaching the end of file

6) show record count of same contents and different contents, and close the files

Please suggest an easy to understand code for this. Thanks

currently my code is like this:

```py
input_file1 = "Claim_ExportStudyPeriod_NoQuotes_Ap.csv"
input_file2 = "Claim_ExportStudyPeriod_NoQuotes_Jp.csv"
output_path = "Comparison.csv"

t1 = open(input_file1, 'r')

t2 = open(input_file2, 'r')

fileone = t1.readlines()
filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open(input_file2, 'r') as t2, open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in t2:
        if line not in fileone:         
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code writing service. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure to read [ask] and take the [tour] to get started with this community. Your question does not show any affords that you tried something for yourself. I would start with a python tutorial and then follow your numbered steps with a python reference. If you run into problems, this community is the best place to ask :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: @ApoorveBhardwaj Great! you already started? Please edit your question and add you code.

Comment: @lupz I've edited my query. Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along those lines:

```
with open('first.csv', 'r') as f, open('second.csv', 'r') as s, open('out.csv', 'w') as o:
    diffs = 0
    for i, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(f, s), start=1):
        if first != second:
            print((f'row #{i}\n'
                   f'in first file: {first.strip()}\n'
                   f'in second file: {second.strip()}'), file=o)
            diffs += 1
    print(f'Different values on {diffs} row(s), same values on {i-diffs} row(s)')
```